# Trying to understand the discrepancies in disk usage inside raw images and on host disk usage

Tags: disk-space-utilization, qemu, raw-disk

As the title states, I am trying to understand the discrepancies from ncdu and/or du in terms of what I am observing from disk usage. From what I understand, on modern systems, there is difference between disk usage and apparent size.

```
root@pve:/var/lib/vz/images/104# du -h vm-104-disk-1.raw 
30G     vm-104-disk-1.raw
```

However the actual disk usage inside the container is

```
21G     /
```

Since it's a sparse file and size is set to 50GB

```
root@pve:/var/lib/vz/images/104# du -b -h vm-104-disk-1.raw 
50G     vm-104-disk-1.raw
```

Can someone explain to me where the extra 10GB disk usage is being used for in QEMU raw images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sparse file doesn't shrink again, so if you have used that space inside the VM at some point and freed it afterwards, the image file will  not become smaller again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, make's a lot more sense now and I am trying to figure out why this didn't come across my mind. I guess it's because I didn't know. This was very informative.